# How to highlight a range of selected months

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular. All the answers that i came accross are using `jquery` and `javascript`. Few weeks ago there was a requirement in my team that we need a month only picker. But the condition is that we cannot outsource the component from anywhere outside the organization. Not even `bootstrap`, `material` or `primeng`. So I decided to create a custom one from the scratch using HTML and CSS. Here is the screenshot:
[image] 
`app-monthpicker` is a component and on top of it there is a parent component `app-timeselector`.
The monthpicker is working perfectly. But I'm not able to implement the logic for highlighting the selected range of months. All the solutions on stackoverflow and other websites are using `jquery` or `js`. But here We're talking `typescript`. I've created a minimal [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anqtur) and here is one more [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dd1ygq) created by one of the answerer. Can someone help me in this regard please. With `HTML` and `CSS` and `Typescript` only. I badly need someones help here. I want this:

[image]

You can see 6 months from the previous year and all the months from next year also. And they also need to be highlighted if they're in range. For now I need this for 2017 to 2025 only. I don't mind even if you hard-code these values for now.

PS: I'm afraid that my whole implementation is incorrect. Please correct me.

Comment: your demo is not working

Comment: @Amit. I'm sorry Sir. I was making some changes. Fixed now. Please check.

Comment: @Amit. I've completed everything but range highlighting. I'm not able to think in that direction.

Comment: what do you mean by range? users should be able to click on start and the end of the range or what is intended UX?

Comment: OPs want to highlight elements between two selected month

Comment: @Sergey. Yes. You can select start and end month. And in between them all the months should get highlighted. Please see the demo once you'll get a clear picture. :-)

Comment: cool, let me see how I can help. I ll fork your stackblitz and try to produce something today;)

Comment: @SergeyRudenko. Open for bounty now. Please contribute. I'm really in a problem. I have to deliver this component. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, for such a use case you should not re-invent the wheel and leverage a good library that solved this problem. But if you want to make your current code works for the use case here is what can be done:

demo: https://angular-zedvjx.stackblitz.io

implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zedvjx

**At high level:**

- I used approach where overall months are represented by one large
  Array (monthsData) since the use case needs to support months
  selection across years and this way it is easier to iterate over it.
- Then each month view is just a "slice" into this big array, so
  switching between years is switching between the "views" (view here
  is monthArray.slice(viewStart, viewFinish) )
- Also introduced state for the range to keep track of it easier.

Update: wrote an article with cleaner implementation here: https://medium.com/better-programming/month-range-picker-in-angular-8-4ce93ef7d76b

Comment: This is wonderful. I'm sorry you had to go through this. And you're right, We're reinventing the wheel. But I cant challenge my Team lead's decision. I tried to convince though.

Comment: One last request Sergey. I want this the highlight to be exteneded to next year also. Like I've selected Feb, 2019 to Aug, 2020. Then months on both the year should get highlighted. Hope I was able to explain. I do not mind opening this question for bounty also.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the requirement in the question.

Comment: For now it can be 2018 to 2025. But then later I'll externalize that also. My primary concern is that stupid range selection highlight thing. :-(

Comment: I tried few more things but still not able to achieve.

Comment: so when user chooses a year we should show partly the neighboring years? how many months? if it is 2020 how much if 2021 user can see? can you detail that?

Comment: There's nothing fixed as such. You can show as many as you feel like for now. In the screenshot you can see there are 6 months from previous year and all the months from the next upcoming year. :-)

Comment: But they get also need to be highlighted if they are in the range.

Comment: I'm sttill not able to built the required component.  I'll open this question for bounty today. Your help is required anyway. :-)

Comment: cool. yeah i can tackle that but not today:/ if you add bounty please also add expectations and requirements;)

Comment: can you test this: https://angular-p322q4.stackblitz.io? I can do the visual side, but depending on how you are using the data after selection happens, I hope you can do the rest, all you need is to work through the months array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204316/discussion-between-tanzeel-and-sergey-rudenko).

Answer (score 2):

I'll take another aproach. You has four variables:lboundMonth,lboundYear,uboundMonth and uboundYear.

I think that you can has some like, I put and example from october 2020 to febrary 2021

```
lbound:{year:2020,month:10,yearMonth:"202010"} //yearMonth it's the way yyyyMM
ubound:{year:2020,month:1,ueatMonth:"202101"}
```

Futhermore, you create an array with the month. As @Sergey say, we can create an array of  months. But in my case, I'll take that was in the way

```
{monthName: "january",month:1,monthYear:202001}
```

So, when you change the year

```
month=arr.map((x,index)=>{
   return {
     monthName:x,
     month:(index+1)
     monthYear:displayYear+('00'+(x+1)).slice(-2)
})
```

You only need compare in the loop monthYear with lbound and ubound. Some like

```
<div *ngFor="let month of months>
<span [ngClass]="{'ubound':month.yearMonth==ubound.yearMonth,
                  'lbound':month.yearMonth==lbound.yearMonth,
                  'range':month.yearMonth>lbound.yearMonth && 
                          month.yearMonth<ubound.yearMonth
                 }"
       (click)="click(month)"
</div>
```

When you click you has in

```
 click(month:any)
 {
    const my={
       year:this.displayYear
       month:month.month
       monthYear:month.monthYear
    }
    ..asing to lbound or tbound
    //you emit:
    this.ouputToparent({
        lbound:this.lbound,
        ubound:this.ubound,
     })
    //or
    this.ouputToparent({
        lbound:{year:this.lbound.year,month:this.lbound.month},
        ubound:{year:this.ubound.year,month:this.ubound.month},
     })
 }
```

Comment: I appreciate these improvements but can you do something with the highlighting styling. Thats my major issue. thanks :-)